# Cannot access part of state from another React component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My goal right now is to display a status symbol that blinks while my app fetches information from a database, and I want to do that by adding a flag to the store. Basically, I just want that symbol to show up while the info is being fetched, and then to disappear afterwards. This is how I attempt to do it:

`reducer.js:`

```
 switch (action.type) {

     case 'APPS_LIST_INITIATED':
         console.log("APPS_LIST_INITIATED");
         var cpy = Object.assign({}, state);
         cpy.apps = [];

         console.log("Trying to add status flag to the state");
         cpy.statusFlag = true;     


         return cpy;
```

`app_listing.jsx`:

```
    <div style={{opacity: "0.6", float: "right"}}>
        {
            (this.props.statusFlag) ? 
                <CircularProgress 
                    size={.4} 
                    thickness={2} 
                    style={{ 
                      position: "relative", 
                      height: "20px", 
                      top: "-15px" 
                    }}
                />
                : ""
        }
    </div>
```

This is what I've tried so far, but I've found that `statusFlag` doesn't even exist in `this.props`. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: `mapStateToProps` do you have such method?

Comment: I do. It looks like this: 
`const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps ) => {
 return ownProps;
}
`
If I include the flag in this function, does that mean the state passed to the function gets updated?

Comment: `return {
  ownProps,
  flag: state.statusFlag 
}` i suppose it should be something like this

Comment: The problem is that `statusFlag` does not show up in either `state` or `ownProps`, so I can't set it in `mapDispatchToProps`.

Comment: Never mind, it is in `state`, just under a lower level of the hierarchy. Thanks~